# jquery silde effect hiding complete page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I m using this function for loading content dynamically depending on the item chosen from a dropdown. Here's my code:

```
<html>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('.group').hide();
    $('#div1').show();
    $('#stype').change(function() {
        var val = $(this).val();
        if (val) {
            $('div:not(#div' + val + ')').slideUp();
            $('#div' + val).slideDown();
        } else {
            $('div').slideDown();
        }
    });
});
</script>
<form action="a.php" method="post">

  Select:
  <select name="stype" id="stype">
    <option value="1">op1</option>
    <option value="2">op2</option>
    <option value="3">op3</option>
    <option value="4">op4</option>
  </select>
<br><br>

<div id="div1" class="group">
This is div 1.
</div>

<div id="div2" class="group">
This is div 2.
</div>

<div id="div3" class="group">
This is div 3.
</div>

<div id="div4" class="group">
This is div 4.
</div>

<input type="submit" name="submit" value=" Submit " />
</form>
</html>
```

This works perfectly well when I run this on a plain php file. But when I m trying to put this up on my website, and display it as content there, whenever I make a selection from dropdown, the complete page of website slides up and is hidden. (header, breadcrumb, footer, sidebar and stuff)

How to fix this problem?

Comment: It's working for me http://jsfiddle.net/R2n5x/

Comment: Like I said, It does work on a plain php page, but when I run (embed) it on my website, complete website (header, breadcrumb, footer, sidebar and stuff) slides up and hides.
ExtPro's Answer has solved the problem. Thanks

Comment: please check my answer, only 1 thing you have to add.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried replacing

`$('div:not(#div' + val + ')').slideUp();`

With

`$('.group').slideUp();`

Comment: Great. Now I can smack myself in the head and say "why I didn't think of it" :)
Works perfect. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

try change this:

```
var val = $(this).val();
    if (val) {
        $('div:not(#div' + val + ')').slideUp();
        $('#div' + val).slideDown();
    } else {
        $('div').slideDown();
    }
```

for this:

```
var val = $('#stype option:selected').val();
    if (val != null) {
        $('div:not(#div' + val + ')').slideUp();
        $('#div' + val).slideDown();
    } else {
        $('div').slideDown();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just one change and you go....

`$('div:not(#div' + val + ')').slideUp();`

replace with

`$('form div:not(#div' + val + ')').slideUp();`